# How to change background color through component of svelte

Tags: css, svelte, svelte-component

My program look like this

```html
<script>
    import { islogin, mode } from './stores.js';
    import Login from './Login.svelte';
    import Logout from './Logout.svelte';
    import Menu from './Menu.svelte';
    import Deposit from './Deposit.svelte';
    import Withdraw from './Withdraw.svelte';
    import CheckBalance from './CheckBalance.svelte';
  </script>
  
  {#if !$islogin }
    <Login />
  {:else}
      {#if $mode == 'menu'}
        <Menu />
      {:else if $mode == 'deposit'}
        <Deposit />
      {:else if $mode == 'withdraw'}
        <Withdraw />
      {:else if $mode == 'balance'}
        <CheckBalance />
      {/if}
    <Logout />
  {/if}
```

I have set CSS of first page (Login.svelte)

```css
<style>
    :global(body) {
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
```

and after I log in I want to change the background color on Menu page I try to use background properties on tag `<body>` in `<style>` on Menu.svelte but it seems didn't work, it only change background color of menu button not the entire page.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of one of your inner component code? It would be simplier to guess what's happenning here

Comment: If you are really set on updating the `body`, you will need to use vanilla JS to update the styles on the body element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that sort of cross-component communication without overriding styles, I would recommend using a store as such

```js
// store.js
import { writeable } from 'svelte/store';

export const background = writeable('white');
```

Then using that store to drive a [dynamic style](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-style-property)

```html
<script>
    import { background } from 'store';
</script>

<div style:background-color={$background}>
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

This store can then by updated from anywhere and will change the background color.

Comment: This really helps. Thank!